# primefaces reset page on completion of poll

Tags: jsf, primefaces, polling

Code-Snippet from my xhtml-Site:

```
<div>
    <p:photoCam id="webcam" widgetVar="webcam" listener="#{webcam.capture}" update="response" oncomplete="PF('poll').start()"></p:photoCam>

    <p:poll id="capture" intervall="1" oncomplete="PF('webcam').capture()" stop="#{timeController.stamped}"></p:poll>               

    <p:outputLabel styleClass="#{timeController.stamped ? 'colouredGreen' : 'colouredRed'}" id="response">
        <p:spacer width="50" height="50"></p:spacer>
    </p:outputLabel>

    <p:poll intervall="3" widgetVar="poll" autoStart="false" oncomplete="PF('triggerReset').click()"></p:poll>

    <p:commandButton id="triggerReset"  widgetVar="triggerReset" style="display:none" actionListener="#{rimeController.resetStamp}" ajax="false"></p:commandButton> 
</div>
```

What I want to do is the following:
1.Scan a Barcode automatically (Webcam checks every second if there is a Barcode in front of it)
2.If a Barcode was scanned >>> my Label turns Green (as Feedback for the one who scans a Barcode) and stop checking for barcodes
3.After 3 seconds (timespan shouldnt be of concern) reset the Label (Default-State >>> red) and start scanning again, or reset the stamp-Var in the backing bean and reload the whole page (first alternativ preferred).

Problem:
I cant get Point 3 to work. The barcode is scanned, the Label turns Green; the webcam stops scanning, but the reset isnt happening. So basically the second poll isnt started as far as i can tell.

My Questions:
What am I doing wrong?
Can i get it to work with the approach i am taking?
If not, how can i achieve something like this?

Approach 2(which doesn't work):

```
<p:poll intervall="3" widgetVar="poll" autoStart="false" oncomplete="triggerReset()"></p:poll>

<p:remoteCommand name="triggerReset" ajax="false" action="#{timeController.resetStamp}"></p:remoteCommand>
```

WebcamBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="webcam", eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class WebcamController{
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{timeController}")
    TimeController timeController = null;
    public synchronized void capture (CaptureEvent captureEvent){
        timeController.registerArrival("1001");
    }
    public TimeController getTimeController(){return timeController;}
    public void setTimeController(TimeController timeController){this.timeController=timeController;}
}
```

timeController:

```
@ManagedBean(name="timeController", eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class TimeController{
    boolean stamped = false;
    public void registerArrival() {
        //parameterList getting filled and data written into database, works fine
    }
    resetStamp() {
        stamped = false;
    }
    public boolean isStamped(){return stamped;}
    public void setStamped(boolean stamped){this.stamped=stamped;}
}
```

+multiple iterations of the commandButton-approach

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: A problem is only reproducable via a [mcve], so including a backing bean in this case. For all we know, the value of the `stop` attribute is still false.

Comment: Added the BackingBeans that are need. I think i can confirm that the stop-Attribute (stamped) is wrong, in my testing the "resetStamped"-Method (which should be triggered by the remotecommand or commandbutton) isnt called, which leads me to the assumption, that sth is wrong with my polls

Comment: Not an [mcve]. Simplify please

Comment: should be better now...

Comment: Zeitcontroller is not used anywhere and webam as a bean does not exist. Please copy/paste in an empty ptoject and try to run it. Tried to do jist an `alert()` in the second poll? or in the oncomplete on the webcam?

Comment: what about my other remarks?